# Why is $!0 = 1$?

Tags: factorial

The subfactorial function is defined as: 
$$!n = n!\sum_{i=0}^n\dfrac {(-1)^i} {i!}$$
I was curious and wanted to find out what $!0$ came out to be.
Since I couldn't use it in the sum above, I used a different method by figuring out $!1$ first and using $!n = !(n-1)n-1$.

It turned out, that if you plugged in $0$ for this, you got $2$.
This seemed odd, so I used a reverse equation, $!n = \dfrac {!(n+1) +1} {(n+1)}$ and plugged in $2$ for $!0$ and it turned out correct.
This still seemed very odd, so I checked it on Wolfram Alpha, which say that $!0 = 1$

So what did I do wrong? And how exactly does $!0$ turn out to be $1$?

Comment: Why couldn't you use it in the direct definition? $!0=0!\cdot \frac{(-1)^0}{0!}=1\cdot \frac{1}{1}=1$.

Comment: The sub-factorial is actually defined combinatorially, and that value is what turns up. It is the number of symmetries on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with no fixed points. There is one bijection from the empty set to itself, and it has no fixed points.

Comment: How do you get $2$ by plugging $0$ into that?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $!n = \dfrac {!(n+1)+1} {n+1}$,  $!0 = \dfrac {!1 + 1} {1}$, $!0 = \dfrac {2} {1}$

Comment: i think the symmetries with no fixed points have been known as  "derangements",

Comment: @user26486 I didn't realize you could do that with summations. I suppose I should know more about them. (I'm in 8th grade currently and really haven't gotten to know about them much.)

Comment: @JamieSanborn $!1=1!\cdot \frac{(-1)^0}{0!}+1!\frac{(-1)^1}{1!}=0\neq 1$

Comment: @user26486 It was the sum that screwed me over, I believed that $!1 = 1!   * \dfrac {(-1)^0} {0!}$. My apologies.

Comment: $!1=0$, when you use the combinatorial defiition, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition you provided:$$
!1 = 1! \sum_{i=0}^1\frac{(-1)^i}{i!} = 1 \left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{-1}{1}\right) = 0
$$Then putting this in the other recursive equation you gave:$$
!1 = !(1-1)(1) - 1 \implies 0 = !0 - 1 \implies !0 = 1
$$

Considering the definition provided on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Derangement):

> In combinatorial mathematics, a derangement is a permutation of the elements of a set, such that no element appears in its original position.

It's clear that the empty set has no elements to put into their previous position, likewise a set with only one element will always have to put that element in the first position.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the usual definition of $!n$ is the number of permutations of an $n$-element set without a fixed point.

Axiomatically, a map $X \to Y$ is defined by its graph, which is a subset of $X \times Y$ containing a unique element $(x,y)$ for every $x\in X$.
In the case $X = Y = \emptyset$, there is exactly one such map, namely the one whose graph is $\emptyset$. This "empty" map is bijective (check the properties from the definition!) and does not have a fixed point.

Hence $!0 = 1$.